# WPF/WCF: Function is not a member of ServiceReference1

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, wcf, service-reference

I am a beginner in developing vb.net and I just linked a WPF to a WCF.
After linking them I added a function to the .svc.vb file (WCF) and it did not synchronize with WPF. In my MainWindow.xaml.vb (WPF) file when I write:

```
Dim client = new ServiceReference1.servicePrincipalClient
```

and I want to do:

`client.MyNewFonction` (this is the function I added to the WCF after linking with WPF)

I have the error :

> MyNewFonction is not a member of
>   MySolution.ServiceReference1.ServicePrincipalClient

Can someone tell me how to fix this error please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service references don't automatically update when the service contract changes.

Use the [Update Service Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx#Anchor_1) menu option to migrate the changes in the service definition into the generated code supplied by the service reference.

Comment: Then could you please [mark this answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)? Thanks.